# Scaling or avoiding migrations when using Django 2.x?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-migrations

I'm just beginning my journey with Django framework and I read that Django developers have made **using migrations mandatory beginning from version 2.0**. I might be old school but I like my database separate from my code. I have always kept my database separate from my code models. I think that the migrations won't scale with the engineering team size.

So my question is 2 fold.

1. Can you not use Django 2.0 without the migrations as I don't think it will scale well and won't fit the CI/CD pipeline?
2. If we can't avoid the db migrations then how can we integrate them in a robust CI/CD pipeline where a model can be changed by different developers from different teams.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think migrations are a problem with a large team. Sure, there's some pains when working with multiple branches and [this post](https://cheesecakelabs.com/blog/really-annoys-django-migrations/) might help. Also it helps to squash migrations often (have someone do that every now and then). But if you use git-flow and have someone check the migration merges (you'll often have dependency conflicts, where `makemigrations merge` will be required), I don't see the big issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You can create your tables manually and set Django to not manage your tables.

After your Django project is configured, just run on your terminal `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`, and django will pick the models on the configured database. This is particularly good if your project will use a already existing or legacy database

Then, you can tell django to not manage your tables on the meta options of the model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # your fields here

    class Meta:
       managed = False
```

[See the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#managed)

But, unless you have a very good way to keep track of your table changes,  I must say this is a mistake. Django migrations help you to keep track on your models changes along the way. It is really helpful if you need to rollback or understand your database history.

Comment: Using `managed = False` makes it very difficult for your developers to actually run unit tests, because they have to create the tables in all the `setUp` methods. It might be possible to set a [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers) for the default database with `allow_migrate()` returning `False` but I'm not sure.

Comment: Very good point, @dirkgroten. I solved that changing `managed = True` on my models Meta on the `setUp()`. It was a pain, though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Migrations are not mandatory, it's not clear what you think has changed in 2.0 to make them so.
2. Migrations are *intended* for large teams. If you avoid them, you'll make things much much harder for yourself and your fellow team members.